# ldapsearch of users and show all their inherited groups

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I'd like to do a ldap search for users to get them and all their inherited groups. 
For example I do this to get the groups of a user:

```
ldapsearch \
-h DomainServer \
-W \
-b "cn=users,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com" \
-s sub "(cn=My Name*)" memberof
```

I know there is this LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx
But I have no Idea how to use it in this case and where to put it. I put it at the end for the memberof and in front before my users name as well which gives me either no result or Bad Search filter.

```
ldapsearch \
-h DomainServer \
-W \
-b "cn=users,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com" \
-s sub "(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=My Name*)" memberof
result: 0 Success

ldapsearch \
-h DomainServer \
-W \
-b "cn=users,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com" \
-s sub "(cn=My Name*)" memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:
result: 0 Success
```

Any idea how to use it here correctly? Thanks!

EDIT: the Filter now works like this:

```
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=My User,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com)
```

BUT actually I'd like to have it work to get it for all users, not just one, so like this:

```
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=*,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com)
```

But thats again a bad search filter :(
My search base is an OU, so I just get some specific LDAP Groups

```
OU=SomeOrganizaionalUnit,OU=SystemAccess,OU=Groups,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com
```

That all works for one specific user, but not for any user.

Answer (score 2):

Find [All Groups a User is a member of including Nested Groups](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+User+Related+Searches-AllGroupsAUserIsAMemberOfIncludingNestedGroups)

This filter is known to works:
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(CN=UserName,CN=Users,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET))

AFIK, it only works with Microsoft Active Directory.

Also, AFIK, in a single LDAP query, you can only get either [All Groups a User is a member of including Nested Groups](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+User+Related+Searches-AllGroupsAUserIsAMemberOfIncludingNestedGroups) or [Resolves all members (including nested) security groups (requires at least Windows 2003 SP2)](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+Group+Related+Searches-ResolvesAllMembersIncludingNestedSecurityGroupsRequiresAtLeastWindows2003SP2) which is a filter like:

```
(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)
```

Comment: I get this: `ldap_search_ext: Bad search filter (-7)`

Comment: It works with `(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=My Name,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com)` But actually I want it for all users and not just my user. :(

Comment: As mentioned, the filter syntax (memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)  is valid. (see also https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531527(v=ws.10).aspx) You may have some formatting or possibly escaping that needs to be performed on the DN of the group.